# Converting a literal string into a regular string

Tags: c#

I have a program that reads from a json file and when it deserializes it into a string it keeps quotes in it. This is the method that updates a winform textbox:

```
public void Update_Textbox(JObject settingsJson, TextBox textboxText, string key1, string key2)
        {
            value = settingsJson[key1][key2];
            serializedSetting = value.ToString(Formatting.None);
            textboxText.Text = serializedSetting;
        }
```

I then have this which reads the file and then calls the method above with the args:

```
var curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            JObject settingsJson = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText($@"{curDir}\settings.json"));

            Update_Textbox(settingsJson, textBox1, "General", "OsuSongsDir");
```

But the result in the textbox becomes

```
"C:\\Users\\ryanp\\AppData\\Local\\osu!\\Songs\\"
```

But i want it to be:

```
C:\Users\ryanp\AppData\Local\osu!\Songs\
```

So its easier for people to edit.

Comment: You're reformatting it as JSON in Update_Textbox - why are you doing that? Just cast to string.

Comment: Oh yes I just added (string) to front, thank you very much :)